# Hopper: What does stack[xxxx] mean?

Tags: disassembly, decompilation, hopper

When using the 'decompiler' tool in Hopper on the `start` function of an application it shows this:

[image: hopper decompiled code]

What does the `stack[2043]` mean, is it 2043 bytes from the top of high memory and its assigning it to the stack?

Here is what the assembly looks like for the same function:

[image: hopper dissasembly]

Comment: Frankly, it's really difficult to interpret the decompilation. For example, it uses the raw register variable `esp` in the output, when `esp` is modified by the prologue -- so which value of `esp` is it referring to? (Evidently the pre-prologue version.) Also the disassembly listing would be more clear if it showed the symbolic declarations for `var_14`, `var_10`, etc. I have a feeling they refer to `-0x14`, `-0x10`, etc. but it would help clear things up. Anyway, given the tenor of your question, I'd say the decompilation will just confuse you and simply to ignore it (or use Hex-Rays).